# next step after blockchain synchronization

Tags: blockchain, ether, synchronization

I am syncing using geth.
do I need to 'save' or secure the blockchain in some way after sync finishes? If i need to pause for some time (kill geth, restart machine) next time i run geth it will automatically pick up from the latest block? Or do I need to tell it from which block to continue?
thnx

Answer (score 1):

The blockchain data it's downloading is written to disk. If you kill `geth` or restart the machine, it will simply pick up from where it left off. There's nothing else you need to do.

Comment: Just to add what @smarx , block creation is a continuos process so is the sync, if your node if offline for some time and come back, it should catch up with the current state by synching all blocks it missed while offline.